# How do I consolidate the Date column?

Tags: sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
    (CONVERT (DATE, mrSUBMITDATE)) as 'Date',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Email' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyEmail,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Phone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyPhone,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Verbal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyVerbal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Web' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyWeb
FROM 
    MASTER30
WHERE 
    mrSUBMITDATE >= (CONVERT (DATE, '2015-01-01'))
    AND mrSUBMITDATE < (CONVERT (DATE, '2015-02-01'))
GROUP BY 
    mrSUBMITDATE
ORDER BY 
    mrSUBMITDATE
```

That produces the following result:

```
Date    SubmittedbyEmail    SubmittedbyPhone    SubmittedbyVerbal   SubmittedbyWeb
2015-01-01  0                       0                   1               0
2015-01-01  0                       0                   1               0
2015-01-01  1                       0                   0               0
2015-01-01  0                       1                   0               0
2015-01-01  0                       0                   0               1
2015-01-01  0                       0                   1               0
2015-01-01  0                       0                   0               1
2015-01-01  0                       0                   1               0


<<snipped>>
```

I want to be able to consolidate so that the totals appear for each day, instead of multiple rows for each day shows up.  Could someone help me out?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What's the schema of `MASTER30`?

Comment: Why are you using `CONVERT` on `mrSUBMITDATE`? Is it not a date already? That's what the 2 conditions in the `WHERE` clause imply. Why not leave it alone then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `GROUP BY` use the same `CONVERT` call as you have in `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    (CONVERT (DATE, mrSUBMITDATE)) as 'Date',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Email' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyEmail,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Phone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyPhone,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Verbal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyVerbal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Submission__bTracking = 'Web' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubmittedbyWeb
FROM MASTER30
WHERE mrSUBMITDATE >= (CONVERT (DATE, '2015-01-01'))
    AND mrSUBMITDATE < (CONVERT (DATE, '2015-02-01'))
GROUP BY (CONVERT (DATE, mrSUBMITDATE))
ORDER BY mrSUBMITDATE
```

Comment: That was it  Thanks Marcin!